# Detect when authorization has finished

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm using animated full page loader to obstruct view until client app has finished loading. Without authorization it was enough to call `IJSRuntime` in ***App.razor*** that would slide the overlay out to show fully loaded content.

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync($"hidePageLoader");
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

However authorization kicks in after the App's `OnAfterRenderAsync` event, so it will slide the overlay away while there is still for a brief moment "Authorizing..." content, then it swaps for actual content. So in simple terms I'm looking for something like `OnAfterAuthorization` (made that up) to be called in one place and work for both `Authorized` and `NotAuthorized` outcomes of any razor component page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just await the `Task<AuthenticationState>` cascaded parameter passed down by `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` component. I've done this from within default layout's `OnAfterRenderAsync`.

**MainLayout.razor**

```cs
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await AuthenticationStateTask;
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync($"hidePageLoader");
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```